Tradingview widget multiple Moving Average colors
Say I want to add two SMAs to my chart:
    "studies": [
          {id: "MASimple@tv-basicstudies", inputs: {length: 18}},
          {id: "MASimple@tv-basicstudies", inputs: {length: 40}},
    ],

the code below will set both SMAs to red
    "studies_overrides": {
        "moving average.ma.color": "red"
    },

how do I set red color for 18 and blue for 40?
